# COM port handle for reading data in c++ vs2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a code to open and read serial COM port in vs2012 c++ which is working fine when I run the code separately in an individual solution.The code is as follow:

```
    Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM3");    // adjust as needed
    if (SP->IsConnected()) // check com port availability
    printf("We're connected"); // send the result


    char incomingData[512] = "";        // don't forget to pre-allocate memory
    int dataLength = 256;
    int readResult = 0;                     //if there is no reading it is -1
    while(SP->IsConnected())
    {
    readResult = SP->ReadData(incomingData,dataLength);
    //std::string test(incomingData);
    res1=strtol(incomingData,&pos1,10); //receive data in right patern
    res2=atof(pos1); //convert the character to integer
    res3=(double)res2; // convert integer to double (as my desired output is a double)
    printf("%f\n",res2); // print the result 
    Sleep(50); // pause so that I can see the coming data 

}
```

in which Serial,ReadData and other functions and headers are defined in a separate header and .cpp file.

My problem occurs when I want to plug the code in my other solution (SOFA Simulation) which I want to use to make a graphical interface. but I get the INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE error and the get last error gives me ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. this is my code in the solution I want to use:

```
namespace sofa
{

namespace component
{

namespace behaviormodel
{

 MyBehaviorModel::MyBehaviorModel():
 customUnsignedData(initData(&customUnsignedData, (unsigned)1,"Custom  Unsigned Data","Example of unsigned data with custom widget")),
regularUnsignedData(initData(&regularUnsignedData, (unsigned)1,"Unsigned Data","Example of unsigned data with standard widget"))
{
 customUnsignedData.setWidget("widget_myData");
}

MyBehaviorModel::~MyBehaviorModel()
{
}

void MyBehaviorModel::init()
{
}
void MyBehaviorModel::reinit()
{
}
void MyBehaviorModel::updatePosition(SReal dt)
{
Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM3");    // adjust as needed
if (SP->IsConnected())
    printf("We're connected");


char incomingData[512] = "";            // don't forget to pre-allocate memory
int dataLength = 256;
int readResult = 0;                     
while(SP->IsConnected())
{
    readResult = SP->ReadData(incomingData,dataLength);
    //std::string test(incomingData);
    res1=strtol(incomingData,&pos1,10);
    res2=atof(pos1);
    res3=(double)res2;
    printf("%f\n",res2);
    Sleep(50);      
}
dx=0.01;
dy=0.01;
dz+=0.01;
using core::behavior::MechanicalState;
mState1 = dynamic_cast<MechanicalState<sofa::defaulttype::Rigid3dTypes> *>      (this->getContext()->getMechanicalState());
helper::WriteAccessor<sofa::core::objectmodel:: Data<sofa::defaulttype::Rigid3dTypes::VecCoord> > xp = *mState1-    >write(core::VecCoordId::position());
xp[0].getCenter()=sofa::defaulttype::Vec<3,Real>((Real)dx,(Real)dy,(Real)(res2);
}


SOFA_DECL_CLASS(MyBehaviorModel)

int MyBehaviorModelClass = core::RegisterObject("Dummy component with a custom widget.").add< MyBehaviorModel >();


} // namespace behaviormodel

} // namespace component

} // namespace sofa
```

I really can not figure out what the problem is because as I said the problem is not from my serial reader code as I tested it and I know it works fine separately.can you find out where the problem lies?

thanks in advance!

This is my Serial constructor:

```
Serial::Serial(char *portName)
{//We're not yet connected
this->connected = false;

//Try to connect to the given port throuh CreateFile
this->hSerial = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)portName,
        GENERIC_READ ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

//Check if the connection was successfull
if(this->hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //If not success full display an Error
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){

        //Print Error if neccessary
        printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available.\n", portName);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR!!!");
    }
}
else
{
    //If connected we try to set the comm parameters
    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};

    //Try to get the current
    if (!GetCommState(this->hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        //If impossible, show an error
        printf("failed to get current serial parameters!");
    }
    else
    {
        //Define serial connection parameters for the arduino board
        dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
        dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
        dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
        dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
        //Setting the DTR to Control_Enable ensures that the Arduino is properly
        //reset upon establishing a connection
        dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

         //Set the parameters and check for their proper application
         if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
         {
            printf("ALERT: Could not set Serial Port parameters");
         }
         else
         {
             //If everything went fine we're connected
             this->connected = true;
             //Flush any remaining characters in the buffers 
             PurgeComm(this->hSerial, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
             //We wait 2s as the arduino board will be reseting
             Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
         }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry if my question is absurd, but have you tried with`Serial* SP = new Serial("COM3");`?

Comment: _This_ code is pretty much irrelevant. Please show the `Serial` code, a problem is most likely there.

Comment: @DanielStrul Yes I did all the possible combination it works out of this library as a separate code but not inside the namespace.

Comment: @user58697: I edited the code please take a look thank you!

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** use a (LPCWSTR) cast to stop the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong.  Never hard-code a port name either.

Comment: @HansPassant : thanks for your advice nut the problem is that lpfilename is defined as LPCWSTR or LPCSTR in fileapi.h.
do you think it's safe to change a system header?

Comment: @HansPassant: I had also tried to change just the my main code portname to char but it gives me the error :"argument of type char is not compatible with parameter of type LPCWSTR"
PS: I have also checked unicode setting of my project and turned it off.

Comment: @yms: thanks for your advice. I modified my Serial code portname type and now everything is of type LPCSTR (which corresponds to CreateFIleA) and it seems to work (at least now my program connects to the COM port). but now I get the stack overflow error after a certain number of readings. I know it is a memory problem but I don't know where it is from.do you have any idea where the problem may root from?

Comment: @MehdiMadani Stackoverflow errors are usually caused by a recursive method that does not have a proper stop condition. Are you using any recursions in your code? The code fragments you posted in this question do not have enough details to tell. Also you may want to put this into a new question since it is clearly a different problem

Comment: @yms: Thanks! yeah for sure!

Answer (score 0):

The function CreateFile is actually a Macro that is mapped to either CreateFileA or CreateFileW depending on your project (unicode) configuration. As others have mentioned, you should not use a type cast to LPCWSTR to hide the fact that your code is not correct, you just need to use the right type of string.

If a function expects a widestring (LPCWSTR) and you pass it a chunk of memory that contains an ANSI string, it will never work. In this particular case, you can use the function CreateFileA directly so that you can pass your ANSI string to it.